# scale in java not working for (-1,1) or (1,-1)

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to make a simple reflection of word "good":
So i scale the text good by y axis using `g2d.scale(1,-1)` but nothing.

I am using this simple code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class C extends JPanel{

 JFrame frame = new JFrame();

 public C(){
     frame.setSize(500,500);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


     frame.add(this);
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }


 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D)g ;

     gr.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     gr.fillRect(0, 0,250, 250);


     gr.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
     gr.drawString("good",50,50);
     gr.scale(1,-1);
     gr.drawString("good",50,50);


 }

public static void main(String[] args){

    new C();
}
```

When i scale for value>0 for example +2 the scale works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinate system is being changed by the negative value of scale, so drawing at y = 50 is actually drawing at y = -50. You can

1. Draw the text at the appropriate position, taking into account the negative scale factor eg gr.drawString("good",50,-50);
2. Make a call to translate to prior to drawing the String (eg `gr.translate(0,-100)`

Either way, consider not changing the Graphics transform, but use an external transform and reset the Graphics transform afterwards

```
AffineTransform previous = gr.getTransform();
AffineTransform newTransform = new AffineTransform(previous);
newTransform.scale(0,-1);
gr.setTransform(newTransform);

gr.setTransform(previous);
```